# How to implement pessimistic locking in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have link on ID column, when user click on link there is an EDIT button.
When click on EDIT user can make changes.

But, I want to ensure that two users can't edit in same time, and when one user click on edit that all users can't see edit button till save/commit record.
Also to leave message eg. Record is editing by another user, please try later.

I can add one column in table eg. editing number(1), but how to change this column to 1.
when user click on EDIT button?

Answer (score 2):

**To give an answer on you question:**
You can create a dynamic action which will be triggered on pageLoad. That DA should then update the column to 1 or Y.

**!! Warning**:
But how will you make sure, that the column will be updated back to 0 or N? Buttons and actions which closes the modal, can update the column back to its initial state, but the X - Close Window button won't. And what if your browser closes or crashes?

In that case, you would be left with a record, which can't be edited anymore by anyone, since that record is still indicated as currently being edited.

**I strongly advise not to go down that road!**
Instead, trust Oracle APEX's `Prevent Lost Updates` and `Lock Row` mechanism's. These are available in the `Settings` part of the `Automatic Row Processing` process.

Comment: Thanks @Giliam, I can schedule a job in case of crashes. I use normal page for editing instead of modal dialog. Can I update column again to 0 or N with DA, after click on SAVE button.

Comment: But if this isn't a modal, then what makes sure that after doing a SAVE action, the user starts editing some more, while the column already has been set back to its OPEN state. Like I said before, this is not the way to go.

Comment: @Goku but Giliam is right, why is conventional optimistic locking not good enough for this page?

Comment: I don't use Automatic Row Processing to save data. I use PL/SQL CODE.

Comment: I tried with hash values, to compare data from table before header and in the moment of clicking SAVE. But user can wast time to edit record and then get message that record is out of date. In this case user must edit record again.

Comment: You are really doing it the hard way... But in that case, build your own optimistic locking mechanism in the PLSQL code by 1. select AND LOCK the row 2. Track whether there are changes between the unmodified data (before you went editing) and the data in the locked record, f.e. with a MD5 hash over all the columns 3. If the hashes are still equal, meaning the data has no changes in the mean time by someone else, you can continue with the your actual update..

Comment: @Giliam it seems that Goku isn't happy with the concept of optimistic locking - "user can waste time..."  Yes, but realistically how often?  And wouldn't Oracle have built pessimistic locking into APEX natively if it were practical and sensible to do so?!

Comment: @TonyAndrews I agree with you, not often but, I want to avoid that :)

Comment: @Goku avoid that, but risk a user having to wait a few minutes for the scheduled job to tun, to edit a record that another user locked and abandoned? :-)

Comment: Very bad idea. If a user clicks on "Edit" and goes to lunch... what to you do ?? Do not reinvent the wheel, Apex is a very solid framework. For a problem like yours there is "Lost Row Detection" - which is built into the apex forms. You can implement your own version of that as well.

Comment: Thank you all! I'll think about it. Why question is closed?